# Vue binding input of known and unknown values

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, data-binding

I have an object that holds both known and unknown values. Quantity is unknown, Type is known. I want to present the user inputs for every Type and the user enters quantity. How do I model this in Vue?

```
  data() {
    return {
      message: "",
      order: {
        orderDetails: [], // end result, after user made choices: [{ quantity: 1, productType: "A"}, {quantity: 1 , productType :"B"}] ,
      },
      productType: ["A", "B", "C", "D"],
    };
  },
```

and

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="(item, index) in productType" :key="index">
    <input type="number" v-model="?order.orderDetails[index].quantity?" /> {{ item }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

and the desired output is kinda like this

```
<ul>
  <li><input type="number"> A </li>
  <li><input type="number"> B </li>
  <li><input type="number"> C </li>
  <li><input type="number"> D </li>
</ul>
```

obviously this is not working cos the vmodel object doesn't exist. I don't think that initialising the model with null quantities is the correct approach as the Types will be coming from an API call and will not be hardcoded. Is a computed property the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is best to structure your data model to reflect the view. If you keep the product types and the quantities separate, then you're going to have a difficult time trying to pair them together in the view because the data will be all over the place.

You want to have a list of inputs for each type, so your data model can be an array of objects where each object has a `productType` property and a `quantity` property. Initially each quantity will be 0.

```js
data() {
  return {
    orderDetails: [
      { productType: 'A', quantity: 0 },
      { productType: 'B', quantity: 0 },
      { productType: 'C', quantity: 0 },
      { productType: 'D', quantity: 0 },
    ]
  }
}
```

But let's say you don't know what the types will be ahead of time (perhaps you fetch the types from some API), so you can't structure the data like that straight away in the code like I have shown. So then all you have to do is dynamically construct the `orderDetails` array once you have the array of types:

```js
data() {
  return {
    orderDetails: []
  }
},

async created() {
  // Fetch the types from some hypothetical API
  const types = await fetchTypes()

  // Populate the orderDetails array from the types
  this.orderDetails = types.map(type => ({
    productType: type,
    quantity: 0,
  }))
}
```

Now it's just a 1-to-1 mapping between the data and the view!

```vue
<ul>
  <li v-for="(item, index) in orderDetails" :key="index">
    <input type="number" v-model="item.quantity">
    {{ item.productType }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Your view (template) should be very simple with no complex data processing; it should be just a simple function of the data.

Comment: Yea, that works! This was my approach as well but I was gravitating (as indicated) towards a computed property. created makes much more sense. Thx!

Comment: You can't really do something like this easily with a computed property because the data returned from a computed property will not be reactive (this is by design; computed properties get recalculated whenever some dependent data is changed).